# How do I select more Raycast Mask layers for XR Ray Interactor at run time?

Tags: unity, c#

[image]

I want to select more layers for Raycast Mask at runtime when I click a button.

I tried `GetComponent<XRRayInteractor>().raycastMask.` but couldn't find an option to select more layers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bitmask, so you can shift a `1` bit into the position corresponding to each layer's index, then use `|` (bitwise OR) to combine these into a mask with exactly those chosen bits set to `1` and the rest left at `0`.

```cs
int firstLayer  = 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("First Layer Name Here");
int secondLayer = 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Second Layer Name Here");
int thirdLayer  = 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Third Layer Name Here");

GetComponent<XRRayInteractor>().raycastMask = firstLayer | secondLayer | thirdLayer;
```